# Download selected pdf files from a datatable

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

my controller looks like

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileResult methodname(string files)
    {
        String CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        string dir = filepath + "/" + CurrentDate + "/";
        string[] fileList = files.Split(",");
        var count = fileList.Length;
        try
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Enter Action with user name " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName"));
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var ziparchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        ziparchive.CreateEntryFromFile(dir + fileList[i], fileList[i]);
                    }
                }
                return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Attachments.zip");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: to download the selected files from the datatable as a zip file

Comment: ok and what's the problem with the current method?

Comment: The controller is getting the selected file list in the parameter and while returning the file, again the controller is getting executed and this time the parameter is having null value. Can you help me with this.

Comment: so you get a nullreferenceexception? which  parameter is having null value?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding the following line just below the click event:

```
event.preventDefault();
```